# "Untracked Files Prevent Checkout" except its vcs.xml

Tags: git, intellij-idea, commit

I'm trying to merge a branch with the master, so I checked out the master but now it won't let me do the merge:

Untracked Files Prevent Checkout
Move or commit them before checkout
.idea/vcs.xml

I can't move or delete the file, because it will disengage the VCS from this project
I can't commit it because it's not an option when I try to commit
I can't switch to the branch to see what I can do from that end, because I get the same error message.

How can I fix this and how can I prevent it from happening again? Do I need a .gitignore file that is set up to exclude everything from the .idea folder?

Comment: I don’t quite understand how you can get the same error message when you commit the vcs.xml in master and then checkout the other branch, because then it’s well… not an untracked file anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure either. It doesn't actually show the vcs.xml file in my project file structure or in the unchecked files box that pops up when I try to commit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The branch you're trying to merge has this file checked into it, but the `master` branch has untracked (and possibly in `.gitignore`).  When you're trying to merge the other branch, Git prevents you from overwriting those files because you might care about them (after all, one side has them tracked).

You have some options:

- Delete the file and merge, which will include the version from the branch you're trying to merge.
- Change the branch (or have the author of the branch change the branch) to not include the file you don't want to override and make sure it's in `.gitignore`.  If this is a file specific to a given editor, it probably doesn't belong in version control, since different people use different editors and different settings.
- Save the file to somewhere else, merge, and then determine what to do after you see the result of the merge.

Comment: Thanks the third option worked for me, move the files outside the repo, then checkout to master and after that move back the files that shall be ignored by master.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the .idea folder and right-click on vxs.xml and have the IDE add that file to to .gitignore. Then you should be able to Pull from GitHub.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that worked for me was that in pycharm, when it asks for smart checkout, don't use the smart checkout. go through and merge manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should:

1. create a .gitignore file in local project's folder,
2. If you use PHPstorm, press "NO" button, when PHPstorm ask you "add .gitignore file to Git?"
3. fill it:

   /.gitignore

   /.idea/*